# scp /path/to/local/file myusername@server.com creates a new file in local directory?

Tags: ssh, scp

scp was working fine, but now when I do

```
$ scp /path/to/local/file myusername@servername.com
```

it doesn't ask for my password, but returns nothing immediately, and a new file named "myusername@servername.com" is created in the directory.

Also, I have not problem ssh to server, it asks for my password and I could log in successfully.

```
$ ssh myusername@servername.com
```

I did some configuration to set up VIM as IDE for C++ over the weekend, so I might have messed something? I've also created a new anaconda environment for running Python3, if these information help.

Answer (score 20):

You need to tell `scp` you're copying to a remote, using `:` and (optionally) a path on the target:

```
scp /path/to/local/file myusername@servername.com:/path/to/remote
```

If you just specify `:` it will use the default path, probably `myusername`'s home directory on `servername.com`:

```
scp /path/to/local/file myusername@servername.com:
```

(Thanks to [Stephen Harris](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/168757/stephen-harris) for [pointing out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311383/scp-path-to-local-file-myusernameserver-com-creates-a-new-file-in-local-direct/311384?noredirect=1#comment547630_311384) that the remote path is optional.)

Comment: You typically don't need a remote path, but you _do_ need the `:`.

Answer (score 13):

Because `scp` can be used to copy files *to* a server, or *from* a server the program uses the presence of the `:` to determine which way to send.  Without a `:` there is no *hostname* and so it assumes both files are local.

So

```
scp x a@b
```

will treat both `x` and `a@b` as local files.

You don't *need* to specify a target path, but you do need the `:`

```
scp x a@b:
```

If there's no path specified then it will use the default directory (typically the remote `$HOME`), same as if you'd specified `a@b:.`

Answer (score 2):

By default, `scp` assumes that you want a local file unless you specify where you want the file on the remote server with `:`.

For example, `scp /path/to/local/file myusername@servername.com:./` will do what you intend: to create a file at the default directory of `myusername` on `servername.com` called `file` with the contents of `/path/to/local/file` on your computer.